# German letters in overleaf / Latex, Problem U308

Tags: overleaf

so I am just trying to write something in german in overleaf, but  nothing is working for special german letters like ä,ü,ö... .
does anyone know how to resolve this problem with  (Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̈ (U+0308) ) ?

[my code and the shown problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odg5R.png)

i tried to use latin1/ ansinew and utf8 for inputenc, they work properly on Texmaker, but not on overleaf  ?

please some help, I am stuck since hours.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Durchführung}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Beugungseffizienz in Abhängigkeit der Intensität der 
Schallwellen }

\chapter{März}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add your example as text to your question so we can copy&paste to test it?

Comment: yeah one second

Comment: this code doesnt show errors, but it doesn't show the required letters either

Comment: it sitll not working neither with utf8 nor without. and it is showing the same errors:

Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̈ (U+0308)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 ...gkeit der Intensität der Schallwellen}{3}
                                                  {}%
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code and error messages. Please read the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions, particularly on using images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't really use an `ä` in your code. For example if one checks your word `Abhängigkeit`, it will give

```
   0041   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   0062   LATIN SMALL LETTER B
   0068   LATIN SMALL LETTER H
   0061   LATIN SMALL LETTER A
   0308   COMBINING DIAERESIS
   006E   LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   0067   LATIN SMALL LETTER G
   0069   LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   0067   LATIN SMALL LETTER G
   006B   LATIN SMALL LETTER K
   0065   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
   0069   LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   0074   LATIN SMALL LETTER T
```

which builds the ä with a normal `a` and then the dots. If one uses a real `ä` instead:

```
   0041   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
   0062   LATIN SMALL LETTER B
   0068   LATIN SMALL LETTER H
   00E4   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
   006E   LATIN SMALL LETTER N
   0067   LATIN SMALL LETTER G
   0069   LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   0067   LATIN SMALL LETTER G
   006B   LATIN SMALL LETTER K
   0065   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
   0069   LATIN SMALL LETTER I
   0074   LATIN SMALL LETTER T
```

If you retype them, the following code works:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/bnyhqzdjmfmx

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Durchführung}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Beugungseffizienz in Abhängigkeit der Intensität der Schallwellen}

\chapter{März}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanssw thank you very much you gave a good for the solution, the problem is, a you mentioned ,was that some letters were not really what they should be, (it is because 2 of us are working on the report) so my letters were fine, but not those of my partner